# Ajax call failed to load content from Controller in Magento 2.1.4 Enterprise Edition

Tags: magento2, php, ajax, jquery, magento2-enterprise

I am trying to do an auto search for my html form. I requesting to controller for data but it is saying:

**Failed to load http://127.0.0.1:8080/Project/abc/abc_foo/foocon/: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.**

I added following code to my controller:

```
Header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');

Header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');

Header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials','*');
```

Please find the ajax code below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#inputName").keyup(function(){
    var valueCount = $("#inputName").val();
        if(valueCount.length > 3){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/Project/abc/abc_foo/foocon/',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'post',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify({ "inputName": $('#inputName').val()}),
                processData: false,
                success: function (data, textStatus, jQxhr) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Please suggest the solution. I checked several times but not getting any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually set the header in the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
     url: "http://your-url...",
 headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
});
```

or you can set not to use cross-domain defaults, so it will keep the X-Requested-With header in the ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://your-url...",
 crossDomain: false
});
```